# SQL query for a polymorphic relationship - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> Could one kindly advise me how i display users with an overall_ratings
>   of 0. how do i display users with an `overall_ratings` of 0? currently
>   i can display users ratings of 0 but i do not know how to retrieve
>   those users (the user information) who have a rating of zero

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170202214851) do

  create_table "rates", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "rater_id"
    t.integer  "rateable_id"
    t.string   "rateable_type"
    t.float    "stars",         null: false
    t.string   "dimension"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "rates", ["rateable_id", "rateable_type"], name: "index_rates_on_rateable_id_and_rateable_type"
  add_index "rates", ["rater_id"], name: "index_rates_on_rater_id"


  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                           default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                   null: false
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
  end
end
```

rate.rb

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rater, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :rateable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

in my user.rb model i have the method `overall_ratings` which displays the over all rating of a user

method in user.rb

```
 def overall_ratings
    array = Rate.where(rateable_id: id, rateable_type: 'User')
    stars = array.map {|user| user.stars }
    star_count = stars.count
    stars_total = stars.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x }
    score = stars_total / (star_count.nonzero? || 1)
  end
```

terminal

```
2.3.0 :109 >   user = User.find(20)
2.3.0 :116 >   user.overall_ratings
  Rate Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "rates".* FROM "rates" WHERE "rates"."rateable_id" = ? AND "rates"."rateable_type" = ?  [["rateable_id", 20], ["rateable_type", "User"]]
 => 3.5
```

> i am trying to find users who have a rating of 0, but i am unsure how
>   to write the right sql to display this information

```
users = User.all
2.3.0 :189 > users.map(&:overall_ratings)
=> [4.0, 3.75, 0, 3.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.0, 0, 0, 3.0, 3.5, 0, 0, 0, 0] 


2.3.0 :197 >   users.map(&:overall_ratings).delete_if{|i|i>=1}
 => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

> question: how do i display users with an `overall_ratings` of 0? currently i can display users with the ratings of 0 but i do not know how to retrieve those users who have a rating of zero. your help
>   would be much appreciated

i am unsure...i am trying the below but i know its incorrect

```
2.3.0 :203 >   users_with_ratings_of_zero = users.map(&:overall_ratings).delete_if{|i|i>=1}
=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

2.3.0 :208 >   users_with_ratings_of_zero.map(&:users)
NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for 0:Fixnum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
users_with_ratings_of_zero.map(&:users)
```

This is failing because you have mapped the users to an actual number (the rating) in this line:

```
users_with_ratings_of_zero = users.map(&:overall_ratings)
```

The above code turns that list into just numbers: `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` you can't get back the user when all you have is the number `0`

So what you need to do is select out the users... without actually turning them into the number-only. You need to not use `map`

You can do that like this:

```
users_with_ratings_of_zero = users.select {|user| 0 == user.overall_ratings }
```

Comment: wow! thank you soo much......mainly for explanation behind the answer. much much appreciated!